# How can I remove this "zombie" mdadm array?

Tags: linux, raid, raspberry-pi, mdadm

Admittedly I'm not too familiar with MDADM.  I recently set up an array for a NAS, but incorrectly sized the partitions in my setup script, and need to remove the array, re-partition the disks, and re-create the array.

In my Googling, I found the following process to delete an mdadm array:

```
# mdadm --stop /dev/md0
# mdadm --remove /dev/md0
# mdadm --zero-superblock ( /dev/sda /dev/sdb ... )
```

However, I get the following output:

```
sudo mdadm --stop /dev/md0
mdadm: stopped /dev/md0

sudo mdadm --remove /dev/md0
mdadm: error opening /dev/md0: No such file or directory
```

Then, if I attempt to format the drives, `parted` returns an error and the array re-appears in `/proc/mdstat`.

I've tried just running `mdadm --remove /dev/md0` to no avail as well.

Any help with the issue would be appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After some more digging, I found the combination of commands that fixed the issue:

```
sudo mdadm --stop /dev/md0
sudo mdadm --zero-superblock /dev/sda1 /dev/sdb1 /dev/sdc1 /dev/sdd1
```

Comment: mdadm: Unrecognised md component device - /dev/XXX. I.e. the recommendation doesn't work.